# Why does it print 1 at the end?

Tags: c

I don't understand why it prints 1 at the end.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("%d\n", -2&&2);
    return 0；
}
```

Comment: ```-2&&2``` evaluates to true, which is ```1``` in c

Comment: `&&` is logical AND. So the result can only be 0 or 1.

Comment: Why, what did you expect?

Comment: Any integer value other than `0` is considered `True` in `C` while `0` is considered to be `False`. As simple as that. :)

Comment: @Sarques: it's not just integers — pointers that are zero (null) count as false; non-null pointers count as true.  Similarly with floating-point values; zeros are false and all others are true (we can debate NaN another time, please).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sure, thanks for that, actually I was just saying in this problem's context.

Comment: If you have a new question, post a new question - do not change the question beyond recognition after others have taken the trouble to answer the original.  It renders those answers nonsense.  I have rolled it back to the question that the existing answers relate to.

Comment: I would like to add that much of the confusion might result from the fact that a `0` is considered `false` and any other value is considered `true`. So `-2 && 2` is just `true && true` which will return `true`, that is, a non-zero value.

Answer (score 4):

`&&` is a *Boolean* operator, not an *integer* operator.  In C *any* non-zero value is interpreted as `true` when applied to a Boolean operation, while zero is the only integer value regarded as `false` when applied to a Boolean operation.

So:

```
(<non-zero> && <non-zero>) == true
```

then conversely when a `true` result is treated as an integer (as the `%d` format specifier dictates in this case), `true` is represented by 1, while `false` is zero.  So in this case `true` becomes 1.

If you want to print a Boolean result, then:

```
printf( "%s\n", (-2 && 2) == 0 ? "false" : "true" ) ;
```

Strictly the expression:

```
-2 && 2
```

is equivalent to:

```
(-2 != 0) && (2 != 0)
```

Which has strict type agreement since `!=` has a Boolean result from integer operands, and so `&&` is presented with Boolean operands only with no implicit conversion.

Comment: Precedence? In general, the evaluation of  `-2 && 2 == 0` is not the same as `(-2 && 2) == 0` is it?  (It's the same as `-2 && (2 == 0)` — which does produce the same result here, but it is not the same if the terms are not all constants.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Indeed - good spot.  The OP's lack of horizontal space threw me there!  I might invent a language where proximity determines precedence rather then parentheses - apply the closest operator first - everyone will hate me! ;-)

Comment: `x != 0 && y != 0 ? "false" : "true"` and `x && y ? "false" : "true"` make a lot more sense than `(x && y) == 0 ? "false" : "true"` (The fact  that you had to fight precedence should have been a clue.)

Comment: @Clifford — try Stroustrup's proposal to [overload on white space](http://www.stroustrup.com/whitespace98.pdf).  Strict left to right evaluation has precedents too (APL for one example).

Comment: @ikegami : The point was not to suggest a better or simpler solution, but to clarify the semantics of the expression presented in the question.  Had I used your expressions, I'd have to explain them, but it would say nothing about `-2&&2` which is the matter in question here.

Answer (score 0):

Because `-2&&2` is evaluated to `true` = 1 (when you AND two numbers together you will get true unless one or both of the numbers is 0). 
Try changing `-2&&2` to `true && false`; it will print 0.

Comment: But why -2&&2 evaluates to True, because they are all numbers?

Comment: Check @Sarues comment above "Any integer value other than 0 is considered True in C while 0 is considered to be False. As simple as that."

Comment: OK, now I understand. Thank you!

Comment: Because C says that's how it works, @Jaden.  The LHS of the `&&` is evaluated; since `-2` is not 0, it is true; that means the RHS has to be evaluated, and `2` is not 0 either, so it is true, and `true && true` evaluates to `true`, which is `1`.  All non-zero values evaluate to true, but when a value is generated by a logical condition (`&&`, `||`, `==`, `!=`, `>=`, …), the result is either `0` (false) or `1` (true).

Comment: @Wanderer — note that `1` evaluates to true, so your "with the exception of 0 and 1" comment is puzzling.  If you're trying to say "only `0 && 1` will be evaluated to `false`", that's wrong — any expression with one or both terms zero evaluates to false.  If you're trying to say "only 0 and 1 can yield false", that's wrong too — it's zero that leads to false with `&&`, and only zero.  Also note that pointers that are not null are true but pointers that are null are false; also, floating-point values that are zero are false but those that are non-zero are true.  It's not just integers!

Comment: @chqrlie: yes — see my other related [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59233878/why-does-it-print-1-at-the-end/59233930?noredirect=1#comment104680134_59233878) to this question, which does mention NaN as something to be discussed another time.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: OK, I missed that. NaN are indeed beyond the scope of this queston.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `-2&&2` resumes to `1` or `true` (`true` is always `!= 0`, while `false == 0`) based on the boolean arithmetic opration.

And here is how it resumes to `1`:

`&&` represents the logical `AND`, not bitwise `AND`, which is `&`, in C. So you are logical ANDing the values of `-2` and `2`.

Let´s consider the following sentence as one of the statements for the Logical AND (`&&`)-operation:

> If both the operands are non-zero, then the condition becomes true.

`-2` is non-zero, equals `1`.

`2`is also non-zero, equals `1`.

So the result is also `1` (`1`AND `1` = `1`) or `true` represents `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The `&&` operator is for *logical and*, not *bitwise and*.

The expression in your program evaluates as

```
printf("%d\n", (-2 != 0) && (2 != 0));
```

Which is `1` because boolean expressions have value `0` for false and `1` for true in C.

Conversely, if you had written `-2 & 2`, you program would have implementation defined behavior, depending on the representation of negative integers used for the target system. On modern systems with two's complement representation, this bitwise and expression evaluates to `2`. Same value for sign-magnitude representation, but on rare systems with ones' complement representation, the value would be `0`.